# How can I write-protect a worksheet, while permitting link jumping to another worksheet to enter comments?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

There is a very important MS-Excel sheet that I maintain, which I need to share with other colleagues. For every row in the particular worksheet that I maintain, multiple colleagues could leave multiple comments over a period of time.

Here is what I'd like to do:

1. Make the main worksheet that I maintain, 'read-only', with a link/button at the beginning of the row that says "Add comment"
2. Clicking on "Add comment" (link or button), should take the reviewer to another worksheet, where the "row-id" (or some such unique-id about the row number from the original worksheet) is auto-populated, and then a comment could be left. If reviewer name and comment-time can be auto-captured, that is well and good, else I can let it be something that is entered manually.

Now, I am not familiar with VB programming, but I suspect that something similar could be done using VB scripting. If there is an alternative approach to achieve same / similar end, not requiring scripting, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just allow comment objects on the protected worksheet?

home - font - format cells - locked

Then

Review - protect sheet - allow *Select cells* and **edit objects** and put a password on it

Now users can right click to insert a comment.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That is precisely what I tried doing, but the comments are getting unwieldy. I am unable to perform change management properly with it. For instance, I would like to be able to sort by newest comments, but not lose the older ones. Also, I'd like to be able to filter by reviewer. The possibilities of manipulating comments as a standard Excel worksheet are much wider, compared to what I could do with comments alone.

Comment: @icarus74 unless you want to write a bunch of VBA, I'd have to agree with teylyn, this isn't really a job for excel.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a relational database concept. Master/slave or parent/child relationship. Excel is not a database. Your scenario would be a lot easier to create in a database like Access or SQL. With the added benefit that you would have real-time multi-user edit access. Which is something Excel does not do well, either. So, to me this looks like wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn, for taking time to answer. Unfortunately, MS Access or MS SQL is not something that our organization has licenses for, and it is not used here. We are a Linux software shop, Excel, Word, Powerpoint being pretty much the only thing from MS stable. However, I understand your point... I was just hoping to find something, that could at least, take me to particular col. of another worksheet...